# Simulation's problem in a fermentor with Monod kinetics

Tags: scilab

I am simulating a non-linear model (fermentor with Monod kinetics), but I found the output of this model is still fixed at the equilibrium points (initial conditions), Q is input and I used xcos to generate a step input (as a vector) with initial value=2, final value=2.2 and step time=20. I am going to attach my figure. Thanks in advance.
[Output figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK1lQ.png)

```
funcprot(0)
t1=A.time
Q=A.values(:,1)

function dxdt=f(t,x)
    S=x(1);
    X=x(2);

    dxdt=[(Q/20)*(0.02-S)-(0.4/0.67)*(S*X)/(0.015+S)
    (-Q*X/20)+0.4*((S*X)/(0.015+S))]
endfunction
t=linspace(0,100,999);
x0=[0.005;0.0101];
x=ode(x0,0,t,f)
scf(0)
plot(t1,x(2,:))
xlabel('time')
ylabel('X')
ax=gca(),// gat the handle on the current axes
ax.data_bounds=[0 0;100 2.5];   //axis lim
```

Comment: It is impossible to run your example, please define t1 and Q explicitely.

Comment: Moreover, you should remove the last two lines to allow the graph to fit the y scale, and you will see that your step response seems OK.